# Unable to connect to SQL Server via SSL using Spring JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, ssl, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server using from our application which uses Spring JDBC 4.2.5 release. We have the following settings:

1. SQL Server - Is set to require SSL.
2. In the application we have the following connection url:

   ```
   jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<servername>;databaseName=<dbname>;instance=<instance_name>;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;
   ```
3. We imported the SQL Server certificate to the trust store of the server and the the following system properties set: `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` set.

We trying to connect from the application we are getting the following error: "JDBC driver" does not support encryption.

Does anyone know if Spring JDBC 4.2.5 release supports SSL? I can't find any documentation related to this. Also want to know if we are missing a required step?

Comment: SSL support of a JDBC driver has nothing to do with Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:` prefix, you're using the jTDS driver, but the connection properties you use indicate you are following documentation/instructions for the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver.

If you want to use the [jTDS driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/), then use the jTDS properties, for SSL (and certificate validation) you'd need to use:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<servername>/<dbname>;instance=<instance_name>;ssl=authenticate
```

Otherwise, you need to use the [Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc), and change the prefix of your connection string to `jdbc:sqlserver:`.